# QGraphicsItems can only be created on the heap?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

In the constructor of a QMainWindow...

A new circle is created on the heap and passed to the scene, the circle shows up, everythin is working:

```
    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    CustomGraphicsView * view = new CustomGraphicsView(scene,this);

    QGraphicsEllipseItem * ellipse = new QGraphicsEllipseItem (100,100,30,30);
    ellipse->setPen(QPen(Qt::green,10));

    scene->addItem(ellipse);
```

Now we create circle on the stack and pass it by reference. But this time the cricle will never shows up:

```
QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
CustomGraphicsView * view = new CustomGraphicsView(scene,this);

QGraphicsEllipseItem ellipse(100,100,30,30);
ellipse.setPen(QPen(Qt::green,10));

scene->addItem(&ellipse);
```

I guess it gets destroyed before it shows up. But I don't understand why? Why is this not working and what is the rule behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> QGraphicsEllipseItem * ellipse = new QGraphicsEllipseItem (100,100,30,30);
> ellipse->setPen(QPen(Qt::green,10));
>
> scene->addItem(ellipse);
> ```

This works because the `scene` object is in charge of `delete`ing the object which you've allocated via `new`. Somewhere in the depths of the Qt framework, there will be a call along the lines of:

```
delete item;
```

Now with this code:

> ```
> QGraphicsEllipseItem ellipse(100,100,30,30);
> ellipse.setPen(QPen(Qt::green,10));
>
> scene->addItem(&ellipse);
> ```

Consider what happens. The `delete item;` is still there, but it will be applied not only on a pointer to a local object but (probably, depending on the program flow) also to a pointer to an object which no longer lives. The code which performs the `delete` simply has no idea that the object was *not* created via `new`.

Any attempt to destroy an object more than once is **undefined behaviour**, as is trying to use an object which was already destroyed. Your question is a good example of why passing around pointers to local objects should be treated as an especially dangerous action which requires extra caution.

By the way:

> But this time the cricle will never shows up:

That's a mere coincidence. Undefined behaviour means that everything can happen.

Comment: Actually, it's not a coincidence. When `ellipse` (created on the stack) gets destroyed, it removes itself from the scene. So it's correctly destroyed only once. From the docs of `~QGraphicsItem`: *If this item is currently associated with a scene, the item will be removed from the scene before it is deleted.*

Answer (score 1):

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem

> Adds or moves the item and all its childen to this scene. This scene takes ownership of the item.

A `QGraphicsScene` cannot take ownership of an item if it is created on the stack. This implies that the item has to be created on the heap.